# Using ReactFX to resize stage when nodes become invisible?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, rx-java, reactfx

I have a JavaFX dashboard that hides and shows components based on complicated contexts, so ReactFX is a great utility for this.

I created some nested closures by looping through each node, creating an `EventStream` off each`visibleProperty()`, and then subscribing an operation to switch the `managedProperty()` and call `sizeToScene()`. Although my solution works it does not feel very clean. I feel like I should be using a flatmap or something. Is there a more purely reactive way to implement this?

```
    gridPane.getChildren().stream().forEach(c -> {
         EventStreams.changesOf(c.visibleProperty()).subscribe(b -> {
             c.managedProperty().set(b.getNewValue());
             primaryStage.sizeToScene();
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the child list of your `gridPane` is fixed, since in your code you just iterate through it once.

First, why not *bind* `managedProperty` of each child to its `visibleProperty`?

```
gridPane.getChildren().stream().forEach(c -> {
    c.managedProperty().bind(c.visibleProperty());
});
```

To get notified when any child changes its visibility, you can construct and observe a single `EventStream`:

```
LiveList.map(gridPane.getChildren(), c -> EventStreams.valuesOf(c.visibleProperty()))
        .reduce((es1, es2) -> EventStreams.merge(es1, es2))
        .orElseConst(EventStreams.never()) // for the case of no children
        .values().flatMap(Function.identity())
        .subscribe(b -> primaryStage.sizeToScene());
```

Since we assume the child list is fixed, you can get away with something slightly simpler:

```
gridPane.getChildren().stream().map(c -> EventStreams.valuesOf(c.visibleProperty()))
        .reduce((es1, es2) -> EventStreams.merge(es1, es2))
        .orElse(EventStreams.never()) // for the case of no children
        .subscribe(b -> primaryStage.sizeToScene());
```

All that said, I would consider finding a solution that does not tamper with `managedProperty`.
**EDIT:** For example, filter the list of children by their visible property:

```
// your (fixed) list of children
List<Node> children0 = ...;

// list of children that triggers list changes when children change their visibility
ObservableList<Node> children = FXCollections.observableList(
        children0, ch -> new Observable[]{ ch.visibleProperty() });

// children filtered by visibility
ObservableList<Node> visibleChildren = children.filtered(Node::isVisible);

// bind GridPane's children to visible children
Bindings.bindContent(gridPane.getChildren(), visibleChildren);
```

You might need to store a reference to `visibleChildren` to prevent it from being garbage collected, due to the use of weak listeners in JavaFX.

Comment: You're right I should have binded that. I got all caught up in the ReactFX functionaltiy. And although you are right that that the children list is fixed, the `LiveList` is really elegant. Thank you, this works perfectly.

Comment: Btw if its not too involved to ask in comments section. What would you suggest besides using the managedProperty?